# configure react js and python in the same project

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have a project on react js  and python (Django). I would like to know what is the best way to configure them. I don't know much about react so any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Try Googling tutorials about Django and React. There are lots with actual code. There are also integrations with Django and React. http://geezhawk.github.io/using-react-with-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 0):

We've been using [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader) in our production system and absolutely love it. It makes using webpack a pleasure within our django app. We have a number of quite large react apps that are automatically built (this is more a webpack thing than django-webpack-loader) and it's easy to integrate webpack bundles into our templates.

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

.
.
.

{% render_bundle 'react_app' %}
```

We then have [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) providing a restful API that our react apps can consume and interact with. It's quite a simple setup and the flexibility it brings it very powerful.

Make sure you learn react first, and understand the build process with webpack before integrating it into django or else you'll get into a tangle getting everything set up.